# Changing the Order of Double Integrals and Evaluating

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I have the following problem:

[image]

I don't know if I'm doing the problem properly because of the "be clever" thing at the end. Each time I do it, I'm getting an answer of 1. Is there something I'm missing or am I getting the right answer? When I switch the order, the limits for first double integral are 0 to 1 for the outside and 0 to 1-x for the inside. For the second double integral, I get 1 to 2 for the outside and 0 to x-1 for the inside.

Comment: It seems like a typo? Maybe the second integral should have $-1\leq y\leq0$? The "be clever" suggests the integrals should combine into one, but they don't as written...

Comment: It looks you have correctly switched the bounds as given, though.